# Trying to make this class codable and decodable

Tags: swift, class, swift4, codable, decodable

Trying to make this class codable and decodable

```
import Foundation

class Attribute : Decodable {
  
  struct Att: Decodable {
    var number: Int16
    var label: String
    var comments: String
    
    // Everything from here on is generated for you by the compiler
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let keyedContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      number = try keyedContainer.decode(Int16.self, forKey: .number)
      label = try keyedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .label)
      comments = try keyedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .comments)
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case number
      case label
      case comments
    }
  }
  
}

extension Attribute: Encodable {
  
  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(number, forKey: .number)
    try container.encode(label, forKey: .label)
    try container.encode(comments, forKey: .comments)
  }
}
```

I have an error on these lines

```
try container.encode(number, forKey: .number)
try container.encode(label, forKey: .label)
try container.encode(comments, forKey: .comments)
```

with the message

> Use of unresolved identifier 'number'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'label'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'comments'

How do I solve that?

Comment: `extension Attribute.Att: Encodable` although I do not understand why you nest it on a class that has absolutely nothing in it...

Comment: can you elaborate? I do not understand your point. The class has 3 properties. This class will be used to be encoded as Data and transmitted over the network to another computer.

Comment: The class (perhaps unintentionally) has no properties at all, the _struct_ has...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have an empty `class` with a nested `struct` in it? The error comes from the fact that those properties are defined on `Att` rather than `Attribute`, so you need to encode those when extending `Att` to conform to `Encodable`.

Btw, you don't have any special encoding/decoding, so you don't need to declare the encoder/decoder functions manually, the compiler can synthesise them for you.

```
class Attribute: Codable {

    struct Att: Codable {
        var number: Int16
        var label: String
        var comments: String
    }
}
```

Comment: if your answer means changing `struct Att:Decodable` to `codable`, I did that and the errors persist. Can you post how you would do the whole class? Thanks.

Comment: David has explained your issue already. `extension Attribute: Encodable` Attribute does not have a number property. `Attr` has (for some reason)

Comment: @SpaceDog you can see all relevant code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I may have missed something, but the following should work, or at least compile:

```
class Attribute : Decodable {

  var number: Int16
  var label: String
  var comments: String

// Everything from here on is generated for you by the compiler
  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
```